# Нужен ли вопросительный знак в конце предложения?

Tags: пунктуация

Рано или поздно каждый задается вопросом: как курение и алкоголь влияют на потенцию ()

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3):

**Возможны два варианта:**

**Бессоюзное сложное предложение (вопросительная интонация):** Рано или поздно каждый задается вопросом: кАк курение и алкоголь влияют на потенцию?

**Сложноподчиненное предложение (нет вопросительной интонации):** Рано или поздно каждый задается вопросом, как курение и алкоголь влияют на потенцию.

Answer (score 0):

В силу риторического характера вопроса о вреде крепких напитков и никотина, которым задаётся каждый, вопросительной интонации возникать не должно, как и соответствующего ей знака. Отдельная фраза «**Как курение и алкоголь влияют на потенцию**», взятая в качестве темы беседы, тоже не нуждается в особом знаке.